# Update codeigniter cart without using $_POST directly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I figured out using the default code on the codeigniter page ....[here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/cart.html) how to update the cart with the direct `$_POST` content.

```
function update() {

    $data = $_POST;

    $this->cart->update($data);

    redirect('/cart', 'refresh');
}
```

How do I not use the direct post variables since it is not safe?

$_POST var_dumps() as the following array:

```
array(1) { [1]=> array(2) { ["rowid"]=> string(32) "88a180b440d9f4b69e09296c60095867" ["qty"]=> string(1) "1" } }
```

Comment: why is it "not safe"? it's just data. safeness comes from how you're using that data.

Comment: I've just always been told that using `$_POST` parameters directly is not safe. Never really was explained to on why... Is it safe in this case?

Comment: it's not safe if you're, say, building an SQL query string using those post values. But "safe" is contextual... a nail gun is perfectly safe locked up in a toolchest, but totally dangerous when loaded and hooked up to an air compressor...

Answer (score 0):

how can you update cart with out post ? But if you dont want to refresh the page than you can use Ajax / Jquery to update the cart see the link bellow it could help you

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/173140/

[Update cart using jquery and codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755982/cart-is-updated-only-once-using-jquery-and-codeigniter)